# CoreStore sectioned list monitor how to specify .where clause in runtime

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, corestore

I have this code in my init method:

```
self.monitor = CoreStore.monitorSectionedList(
        From<ListEntityType>()
            .sectionBy(#keyPath(ListEntityType.muscle.name)) { (sectionName) -> String? in
                return "\(String(describing: sectionName)) years old"
            }
            .orderBy(.ascending(#keyPath(ListEntityType.muscle.name)), .ascending(\.name))
    )
```

I want to somehow add to this monitor `.where` condition in runtime.

`ListEntityType` is a type alias of an entity called `Exercise`. So each `Exercise` contains one to one relationship `Muscle` (`exercise.muscle`).

each entity has unique identifier attribute.

I have array of muscles identifier which I want to use as filter to display object from sectioned list.

How can loop through this identifiers to add then to .where clause to the `CoreStore.monitorSectionedList`

I probably expect something like this but not 100% sure just assumption:

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = $ARGUMENT")

```
    var predicates = [NSPredicate]()

    if let muscles : [MuscleGroupEntity] = workout?.muscles.toArray() {
        for muscle in muscles
        {
            let myNewPredicate = predicate.withSubstitutionVariables(["ARGUMENT" : muscle.id])
            predicates.append(myNewPredicate)
        }
    }

    self.monitor = CoreStore.monitorSectionedList(
        From<ListEntityType>()
            .sectionBy(#keyPath(ListEntityType.muscle.name)) { (sectionName) -> String? in
                return "\(String(describing: sectionName)) years old"
            }
            .where(format:"%K = %@", argumentArray: predicates)
            .orderBy(.ascending(#keyPath(ListEntityType.muscle.name)), .ascending(\.name))
    )
```

this code crashed with error:

```
-[NSComparisonPredicate rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to
```

I guess this is something from predicate I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710225/nspredicate-dynamic-predicate-with-arguments), but not sure how to use it correctly in my case

EDITED For MartinM comments:

I have ExerciseEntity with a property Muscle.

If I want to get all exercises using just one muscle id it pretty simple:

```
.where(format:"%K = %@", #keyPath(ExerciseEntity.muscle.id), "id_12345")
```

But I want to specify more muscles and define them in runtime. Somehow I need to understand what the format is and what the arguments and how to pass array of identifiers instead just one `"id_12345"`

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but i guess you want a (id IN muscleIds) predicate? Getting all ListEntityTypes where ListEntityType.muscle.id is contained in workout.muscles.ids?

Comment: @MartinM I've added an Edit section to my question above. thanks for help!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch all ExerciseEntity where their muscle.id is contained in a list of muscleIds, you simply use:

```
let muscleIds = workout?.muscles.compactMap({ $0.id }) ?? []
From....
   .where(Where<ExerciseEntity>(#keyPath(ExerciseEntity.muscle.id), isMemberOf: muscleIds))
```

Thats the equivalent of a predicate with format: %K IN %@, ExerciseEntity.muscle.id, muscleIds

This also works negating -> NOT(%K IN %@), same as you can use a !Where in CoreStore.

Compound predicates need to specify how they are linked. CoreStore supports a shorthand for 2 predicates at a time, using logical operators, for example:

```
Where<ExerciseEntity>(yourWhereClause) && Where<ExerciseEntity(otherWhereClause)
```

This is the equivalent to using NSCompoundPredicate like this:

```
NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [left.predicate, right.predicate])
```

You can also pass that compound predicate as argument to the where clause directly if you need a more complex conjunction. You could then also store that compound predicate somewhere and append another compound predicate that fits your needs.

Comment: thanks for help I will try it. what also if I will need to implement search, how can I combine few .where using this one you've suggested in this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511579/corestore-refetch-predicate-nsfetchrequest-issue) you've answered already.

Comment: Should be something like this from this [link](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore/issues/283): `.where(Where<ListEntityType>("%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", #keyPath(ListEntityType.name), searchText) && Where< ListEntityType>(#keyPath(ExerciseEntity.muscle.id), isMemberOf: muscleIds))`

Comment: also if you know how to build an array of predicates to pass into where function. it will be great, so it will be helpful and flexible for me as I can combine any predicates and put it as filter. thanks as always!

Comment: You cant simply pass in a list of predicates. You need to specify how to create a compound predicate out of it, either using AND, OR. This depends on your logic what you need. Think about how you can build your query chain at runtime and what the logic behind the displayable data is. Keep things as simple as possible,

Comment: yea your code works good, but if you can provide an example of compound predicate it will be great!

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the coreStore is a cool wrapper for core-data and there 'where' method is creating an NSPredicate behinds the scenes.  The problem is that you are passing an array of predicates into a method that expects a string.

First turn your array of predicates into a single predicate.  use `NSCompoundPredicate` `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate/1407855-init).

Next, instead of passing it via a string using format, just pass that directly to the where() clause without the word format.  I believe that CoreStore accept NSPredicates directly without having to create them from a format.

I think this will work:

```
 .where(NSCompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates))
```

Comment: thanks Jon, yea I saw that there is some setup over NSPredicate, but time to time it's hard for me to understand how to use syntaxes of functions. I know that I need to learn more about generics. Currently I tried your code but compiler tells me an error `Cannot invoke 'where' with an argument list of type '(NSCompoundPredicate)'` as you can see there are few params which .where takes `format` and `args`

Comment: it looks like the `where` of core store support the && operator see https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore/blob/6f290213fa3da22989b64f09200826765223c101/Sources/Where.swift.  perhaps you can build up a large `where` and apply it?

Comment: are you sure? it looks like you can create a where clause with a predicate - https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore/blob/6f290213fa3da22989b64f09200826765223c101/Sources/Where.swift#L264

Comment: I am not sure, looking at link you've provided looks like we can pass NSPredicate directly, but when I try to use code `.where(NSCompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates))` it shows that error.

Comment: maybe you are on a different version?